# <div> not inside <button>

Tags: html, css

I am trying to validate an HTML5 page with a mobile drop down.

Upon validatin, I am getting an error stating that div is not allowed inside button, but when I try to move the div to wrap the button, it does not show correctly.  The first button shows fine, but the second button or "X" is always showing, and not in the right area.

[FIRST BUTTON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFztq.png) - This what what the first button (open navigation) should look like.
[SECOND BUTTON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N79de.png) - This what the second button (close navigation) should look like.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler pull-xs-right hidden-md-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar">
  <div class="hamburger-icon"></div>
</button>
<ul class="nav-dropdown collapse pull-xs-right nav navbar-nav navbar-toggleable-sm" id="exCollapsingNavbar">
  <li class="nav-item nav-btn"><a class="nav-link btn btn-primary" href="login.php" id="c1">Login</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item nav-btn"><a class="nav-link btn btn-primary" href="index.php" id="c2">Register</a></li>
</ul>
<button hidden="" class="navbar-toggler navbar-close" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar">
  <div class="close-icon"></div>
</button>
```

The CSS is as follows:

```
  .navbar-dropdown .hamburger-icon {
content: "";
width: 16px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 -6px 0 1px,0 0 0 1px,0 6px 0 1px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 -6px 0 1px,0 0 0 1px,0 6px 0 1px;
box-shadow: 0 -6px 0 1px,0 0 0 1px,0 6px 0 1px; }
  .navbar-dropdown .close-icon {
position: relative;
width: 21px;
height: 21px;
overflow: hidden; }
.navbar-dropdown .close-icon::before, .navbar-dropdown .close-icon::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -1px; }
.navbar-dropdown .close-icon::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); }
.navbar-dropdown .close-icon::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); }
```

When I tried to do:

```
<div class="hamburger-icon">
<button>
</div>
```

and so on...

1. The second button (close navigation) is showing when not in mobile view.
2. The first button (open navigation) isn't showing, but I can still click where it is supposed to be, and the second button (close navigation) is showing.
3. The second button (close navigation) isn't showing.

How can I get it so it functions like the first two images without the div's being inside the button's?

Answer (score 1):

try using span instead of div

```
<button class="navbar-toggler pull-xs-right hidden-md-up" 
             type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar">
    <span class="hamburger-icon"></span>
</button>
```

button tag can contain only Inline Elements while div is a Block Element

Comment: Using span no longer causes the issue of the buttons being weird, but the buttons aren't actually visible anymore.

Comment: ... and set your spans to `inline-block`.

Comment: Setting it to inline-block worked perfectly.  Thank you.